# Expression language text box does not exist - WSO2 - Eclipse Juno

Tags: wso2, eclipse-juno

Is Juno a supported Eclipse version? I installed WSO2 Developer studio in Eclipse Juno and was following the tutorial http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BPS300/Quick+Start+Guide. However there is no text box available to enter the expression language. Please check the attached screenshot.

!Editor screenshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1hQk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer Studio does not support Eclipse Juno yet but we are going to support it from next version on ward.

Please use Eclipse Helios SR2 when you are using Developer Studio.

/Harshana

Comment: We just released Developer Studio 3.1.0 M1 with Eclipse Juno support. You can download it from http://builder1.us1.wso2.org/~developerstudio/developer-studio/3.1.0/M1/